# PDFTron: batch update attributes

Tags: pdftron

I want to batch update the titles of all objects in a PDF. Is there a way for me to do this? I had in mind to iterate through the fields and change the `T` values, but this appears not to work; changes to the fields don't persist from one iteration to the next, much less appear in the saved output file:

```scala
PDFNet.initialize();
var doc = new PDFDoc(infile.getAbsolutePath)
var iter = doc.fdfExtract().getFieldIterator

while (iter.hasNext) {
  var field = iter.next
  var obj = field.findAttribute("T")
  if (obj != null && obj.isString) {
      obj.setString("new title")
      println(field.getName) // Outputs "new title"
  }
}

iter = doc.fdfExtract().getFieldIterator
while (iter.hasNext) {
  var field = iter.next
  var obj = field.findAttribute("T")
  if (obj != null && obj.isString) {
      println(field.getName) // Outputs the original title
  }
}

doc.save(new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"), SDFDoc.SaveMode.INCREMENTAL, null)
doc.close
```

Here's [a decompressed, toy pdf](https://pastebin.com/8ejex7Yb) on which I've experimented (uploaded as a text file). It has only one input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `fdfExtract()` which exports (makes a copy) of the fields and returns them as a FDFDoc, so you are editing a temporary object. Which is why later when you call `fdfExtract()` you are getting the same original data, since you never edited the original `PDFDoc`.

If your intention is to edit the `FDFDoc` then keep the reference.
`FDFDoc fdfdoc = pdfdoc.fdfExtract();`

If your intention is to edit the PDF itself, then erase your `fdfExtract` calls and instead call
`pdfdoc.getFieldIterator()`

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan I see that `findAttribute` is described in the API documentation here: https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFTronSDK/java/com/pdftron/fdf/FDFField.html#findAttribute(java.lang.String) I'm not sure if I understood your comment about it.

Comment: Here's [a decompressed, toy pdf](https://pastebin.com/8ejex7Yb) on which I've experimented (uploaded as a text file). It has only one input. And I've [updated my code](https://pastebin.com/S4Y7B976) to use `field.getSDFObj().findObj("T")`, yet the results are the same as before.

Comment: @JellicleCat I see the issue now, thanks for the extra info. I updated my answer.